# Checkbox search in excel VBA

Tags: vba, search, excel, checkbox

this is my first time in this forum. Im a 'newbie' in excel VBA and would appreciate if anyone can help.

I am trying to develop a checkbox search page, where:

- the user is able to use checkbox select up to 4 items to search (in 'Search' worksheet)
- In the data sheet, the data is recorded (by columns) as follows:

Code    Book    Item    Material 1  Percentage 1    Material 2  Percentage 2    Material 3  Percentage 3    Material 4  Percentage 4

- an item, e.g. "Polyester", will appear in columns 'material 1', 2 and so on, depending on the record
- the search should be based on the checkboxes that are checked in the search page
- if multiple keywords are checked, e.g. polyester, wool, cotton, then only rows that has all 3 keywords should be shown

I have searched numerous posts online, and there's one where they delete rows if the keywords are found. Is there any way i can twist the logic and apply to this particular situation?

Been stuck for many days... grateful if anyone can help!

Update 1: I have managed to find something on the internet that deletes the rows if certain keywords are found - however - i would like to do the opposite (this would leave me the remaining correct ones instead...)

Code as below - is it possible to change?:

```
Sub Example1()

    Dim varList As Variant
    Dim lngarrCounter As Long
    Dim rngFound As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    varList = VBA.Array("Here", "There", "Everywhere")

    For lngarrCounter = LBound(varList) To UBound(varList)
        With Sheet1.UsedRange
            Set rngFound = .Find( _
                                What:=varList(lngarrCounter), _
                                Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=True)

            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address

                If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDelete = rngFound
                Else
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                End If

                Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)

                Do Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
                    If Application.Intersect(rngToDelete, rngFound.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                    End If
                    Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Next lngarrCounter

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: [*autofilter with an array as the criteria*](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm)

Comment: Thanks mehow! But how do you add autofilter only if checkboxes are 'checked'? to add more information, i have 'search' worksheet - where users can check the boxes and linked to column of cells, generating true if they're checked. I want to use these checked values for the filter process in 'Search Res' sheet.

Comment: create an array first. loop over the checkboxes and if theyre checked then add their value (text) to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try the `Sheets("Search").Cells.Find([keyword])` command which is similiar to the ctrl+L keys.

If you wish to search more than 1 keyword, you could use the following loop:

```
dim i as Integer
dim vTemp as Variant
dim strFind as String
dim objSearch as Object

strFind = range("searchField").value
vTemp = split(strFind, ",")

for i =0 to Ubound(vTemp)
    Set objSearch  = Sheets("Search").Cells.Find(vTemp(i))
    'Do whatever you like to the object of search
next i
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - but the thing is if its conditional (i.e. only search if checkbox value is true) then Im stuck on putting them into vba language...

Comment: It depends whether you've used ActiveX tools (only for 2007 or later Office) or ordinary tools.
ActiveX is easier, just need to type "if sheets(i).checkboxname then...". For ordinary Excel tools, you may link the checkbox to a cell value and use that cell as a parameter. I haven't written the complete code for what you need, though these commands should be enough to solve your problem.